Changes to Charting`ScaledTicks
The undocumented command Charting`ScaledTicks is used to easily define Ticks for a plot. However, it changed dramatically between Mathematica 12 and Mathematica 13.
In Mathematica 12 the command was
Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"]["lower bound", "upper bound", {"number of major ticks", "number of minor ticks"}]

For example:
Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0, 2.2, {5, 5}]

In Mathematica 13, another option has to be added to the first bracket like "Standard" or "Nice". However, in Mathematica 13, the last option for the number of major and minor ticks does not work. This means
Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear","Nice"][0, 2.2, {5, 5}]

gives the same result as
Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear","Nice"][0, 2.2, {1, 1}]

I looked at
ClearAttributes[Charting`ScaledTicks, {Protected, ReadProtected}]; Definition[Charting`ScaledTicks]

but was not able to identify the problem.
Edit:
Here is the output from Mathematica 12 for both commands. As explained above, the last two numbers define the number of ticks.
Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0, 2.2, {5, 5}]

{{0.,0,{0.01,0.}},{0.5,0.5,{0.01,0.}},{1.,1.0,{0.01,0.}},{1.5,1.5,{0.01,0.}},{2.,2.0,{0.01,0.}},{0.1,,{0.005,0.}},{0.2,,{0.005,0.}},{0.3,,{0.005,0.}},{0.4,,{0.005,0.}},{0.6,,{0.005,0.}},{0.7,,{0.005,0.}},{0.8,,{0.005,0.}},{0.9,,{0.005,0.}},{1.1,,{0.005,0.}},{1.2,,{0.005,0.}},{1.3,,{0.005,0.}},{1.4,,{0.005,0.}},{1.6,,{0.005,0.}},{1.7,,{0.005,0.}},{1.8,,{0.005,0.}},{1.9,,{0.005,0.}},{2.1,,{0.005,0.}},{2.2,,{0.005,0.}},{2.3,,{0.005,0.}},{2.4,,{0.005,0.}},{2.5,,{0.005,0.}}}

And for the other case:
Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0, 2.2, {1, 1}]

{{0.,0,{0.01,0.}},{2.5,,{0.005,0.}}}


If it is not possible to make the command work as intended in Mathematica 13, is there a simple way to reimplement the original definitions from Mathematica 12 in a new custom command?

Can you please include what the expected output from Mathematica 12 is, because I don't have access to version 12 ...

try {Identity, Identity} in place of "Linear"?
